# Visual Studio lost its font settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts, settings, razor

I woke up in the morning, turned on my computer and launch VS10 and found all the fonts are messed up! I had one type of font and now the code is in a totally different font, not only that but also the windows like the Command Window, Find Symbol results window etc on the bottom of VS, even their fonts are changed.  Moreover the code in .cshtml files are highlighted.  I've never experienced this before.

Has anyone else experienced this weird issue, and how do I get back my old setting and how do you turn the .cshtml files coding highlighting off.

Thank you,
Ray.

Answer (score 2):

Try 'Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset All Settings' on the menu.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that helped though the bottom command windows' fonts are still off, do you by chance know how to get that back?  Thanks.

Comment: I just re-launched VS and all the fonts are messed up again :(